# Retrieve info from 2 tables django

Tags: django

I am trying to get the info from a second table in django, but cant make it work...

The query in MYSQL would be like this...

```
SELECT search_products.model, search_products.year, search_products.size, search_avg_price.estimated_price
FROM search_products
left JOIN search_avg_price
ON search_products.model=search_avg_price.model and search_products.size=search_avg_price.size and search_products.year=search_avg_price.year
```

I have a table which has a series of products with 3 characteristics: model, size and year.

On another table I have the average price for each combination of model, size and year.

I wanted to retrieve the estimated_price field from table avg_price to use it on my template together with the fields from the products table.

Everything works but I do not get any result for the field from the table avg_price, only the fields from the products table...

My models (I wanted them to join on three fields: model, size and year. Not sure if I did it correctly as I am not specifying it anywhere):

```
class Avg_price(models.Model):
 model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
 size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 estimated_price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Products(models.Model):
 product_id =models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 link_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
 size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 type=models.ForeignKey(Type)
 avg_price = models.ForeignKey(Avg_price)

 def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
   return self.location
```

My View

```
def index(request):

latest_products = Products.objects.all().prefetch_related("avg_price")

if request.POST.get('modelo') is not None and request.POST.get('modelo') != "":
    latest_products = latest_products.filter(model=request.POST.get('modelo'))

template = loader.get_template('search/index.html')
context = {'latest_products': latest_products[0:20]}
return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

And the template

```
{% if latest_products %}
  {% for product in latest_products %}
      <ul>
        <li id="col_one">
          <h5>{{product.avg_price.estimated_price}}</h5>
          <h5>{{product.model}}</h5>
```

I get product.model but not product.avg_price.estimated_price

Comment: Does replacing `prefetch_related()` with `select_related()` help?

Comment: No... tried with select_related before but did not work as well...

Comment: You really checked your `product` *has* actually an `avg_price` which is not `None` ?

Comment: When I do the query on SQL direct to the database I get two records... but when I do the above through django I did not get any result...